# Are there other ways to output web video stream on java panel?

Tags: java, sockets, video, video-streaming

I wrote code that when I click a java swing button then JAVA plays video stream that python client sends to web. (I use vlcj and mjpg-streamer to play video stream on java swing JFrame.)

Unfortunately It takes all of JFrame spaces but I want to make part of JFrame plays video stream such as JPanel or something. I want to know if there are other ways to make JPanel plays video stream. I hope you help me and thank you for reading.

Below is my code that uses JFrame, VLCJ.

```
SearchIcon2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String number = CCTV.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (number.equals("no. 1")) {
                    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent component = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

                    final JFrame fs = new JFrame("no. 1");
                    fs.setContentPane(component);
                    fs.setBounds(100, 100, 850, 518);
                    fs.setResizable(false);
                    fs.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    fs.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                            component.release();
                            fs.setVisible(false);
                            fs.dispose();
                        }
                    });
                    fs.setVisible(true);
                    component.mediaPlayer().media().play("http://IP:8090/?action=stream"); // sorry it is my ip.
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `component` as content pane, so it covers all of JFrame.

You can use the layout manager of JFrame (default is BorderLayout) or add a JPanel as content pane and add other components using layout manager.

```
// JFrame layout example
final JFrame fs = new JFrame("no. 1");
fs.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
fs.add(newPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



// JPanel example
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
LayoutManager mgr = ...
panel.setLayout(mgr);
panel.add(component); // maybe layout manager specific parameters also
fs.setContentPane(panel);
```

Comment: Thank you but It still plays video covering every frame and It doesn't play video only when BorderLayout is CENTER.